# How to fix this js script to send a value by method post

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, model-view-controller

I have this Javascript and I want to click ok and call detel method in my controller,
but its not working and I don't know why.

I need to but two values in this submit:
`id and name`.

Also I don't know what url it should be   because the method doesn't change. I'm in delete right now but in get method.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "",
                        data: { name: ViewBag.ProductName, id: ViewBag.ProductID },
                        success: function () {
                            alert("succes");
                            $("#result").html('submitted successfully');

                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("failure");
                            $("#result").html("there is error with submit");
                        }
                    })
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Anuluj: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: What does "Anuluj" mean?

Comment: It's mean cancle.   But its only for closing the window.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/ControllerName/ActionName",
                    data: { name: '@ViewBag.ProductName', id: '@ViewBag.ProductID' },
                    success: function () {
                        alert("succes");
                        $("#result").html('submitted successfully');

                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("failure");
                        $("#result").html("there is error with submit");
                    }
                })
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Anuluj: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```